# How to sort a different column from varImp function in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I'm using the varImp(model, scale = FALSE) function for multiclass and got a result of 20 most important variables with three columns since there are three classes.
It is currently sorted based on the first column, but **is there any way to sort it based on the second column**? I tried sorting it and convert to dataframe, it doesn't work: cannot coerce class ‘"varImp.train"’ to a data.frame.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example and show expected output for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using randomForest with caret, otherwise the `varImp()` function will not work.

please provide this information in your question.

So you can store the varImp() results and sort after:

```
library(caret)
rf = train(Species ~ .,data=iris,method="rf",trControl=trainControl(method="cv"),importance=TRUE)

varImp(rf,scale=FALSE)
rf variable importance

  variables are sorted by maximum importance across the classes
             setosa versicolor virginica
Petal.Length 22.013    33.4341    27.738
Petal.Width  22.454    32.3445    30.897
Sepal.Length  6.649     8.6931     8.569
Sepal.Width   4.420    -0.8063     3.560

res = varImp(rf,scale=FALSE)$importance
```

Sort by second column,

```
res[order(res$versicolor,decreasing=TRUE),]

                setosa versicolor virginica
Petal.Length 22.013431  33.434069 27.738319
Petal.Width  22.453571  32.344497 30.897214
Sepal.Length  6.649072   8.693132  8.569421
Sepal.Width   4.419712  -0.806256  3.559570
```

Comment: Thank you very much!